# Grounds For Divorce in Massachusetts

Tags: united-states, divorce, massachusetts

If my wife wants to divorce me, does she need my consent? Does she need grounds - like I cheated (which I didn't and would never do).

Comment: https://www.mass.gov/info-details/massachusetts-law-about-divorce might be worth reading and it recommends https://www.masslegalservices.org/FamilyLawAdvocacyForLowAndModerateIncomeLitigants

Comment: Thanks Henry. That pretty much answers it.

Comment: I've edited the question so that it is not asking for personal legal advice.

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: @Seekinganswers Because it seems to lack prior research. A simple internet search already answers OPs question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The State of Massachusetts has "no fault divorce" as does every other U.S. state. Either spouse may unilaterally petition for divorce without grounds for divorce that have to be proven with evidence in court. A statement of a spouse under oath that there are irreconcilable differences in the marriage conclusively establishes a right to file for divorce.

> What if my spouse wants a divorce but I don’t?
>
> It is nearly impossible to contest a divorce. Since this state allows
> divorce due to “irreconcilable differences” all your spouse needs to
> prove is that they cannot live with you or no longer love you. For
> many people, this is a sign that it is time to move on since courts
> are not in the business of forcing an unhappy individual to remain
> married.
>
> If your spouse files a divorce based on fault, you can dispute the
> reasons you are at fault. But this will likely convert your divorce to
> a “no fault” divorce rather than stop it completely.

([Source](https://www.infinlaw.com/faq/50-questions-massachusetts-divorce/))

Marital fault is not considered on the merits of child custody, property division, or alimony in Massachusetts.